# HTML- how to have checkbox and slider on the same line

Tags: html, inline

I have a text label, a checkbox and an opacity slider (its for an openlayers map) which I'd like to get on the same line, by default they're on separate lines.

[image: Eg]

Any idea how to line them up on the same line? My code is

```
        <li><span>Parish</span>
          <fieldset id="layer6" style="border:none">
            <label class="checkbox" for="visible6">
              <input id="visible6" class="visible" type="checkbox"/>
            </label>
            <label></label>
            <input class="opacity" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01"/>
          </fieldset>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default display for labels is inline, and for checkboxes and ranges it's inline-block. So if your range input goes onto the next line, it means that the width of all inputs combined in the first line is greater than that of their parent container. Check the width of the parent container and compare it against the widths of the input fields and labels.

Comment: That's the answer. I edited the width in the fieldset tag to be slightly larger, and it fitted. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```html
<li align="center"><span>Parish</span>
<div align="center">
          <fieldset id="layer6" style="border:none">
            <label class="checkbox" for="visible6">
              <input id="visible6" class="visible" type="checkbox"/>
            </label>
            <label></label>
            <input class="opacity" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01"/>
          </fieldset>
</div>
        </li>
```